# docker-compose - using localhost inside and outside of contaniner aspnet core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I have 2 serviceA and serviceB that I use from my pc at

- https://localhost:5001/servicea
- https://localhost:5002/serviceb

The services could also call each other.

Now I would like to use docker-compose

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  servicea:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}servicea
    ports:
     - "5001:5001"
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://host.docker.internal:5001
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Service1/Dockerfile

  serviceb:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}serviceb
    ports:
     - "5002:5002"
    environment:
     - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://host.docker.internal:5002
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Service2/Dockerfile
```

The services are accessible from my pc via localhost, but not from inside of one container to another

If I log into serviceA container:

- `curl --insecure https://host.docker.internal:5002/serviceB` - working
- `curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1:5002/serviceB` - not working
- `curl --insecure https://localhost:5002/serviceB` - not working (this is what I need)

I have a default dotnet core 3.1 api, using linux containers running in wsl2 with the following default dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001
...
```

Question: How can I (inside a container) access other containers using localhost, and still be able to access the containers from my pc using localhost (outside docker)?

I've tried various combination of setting the ASPNETCORE_URLS and using v3.4 with network_mode: host with no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You don't; `localhost` inside a Docker container means "this container".  But inside a Compose context you can directly call `http://serviceb:5002/serviceB`.

Comment: @DavidMaze so no workaround? Yes, I know I can use the serviceb name, but to be able to run the service both outside and inside docker, without changing the config (there are many services, lots of config), I was hoping for a sln that let us keep using the localhost name

Answer (score 1):

You can set [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) to your service and use them in your services. Or you can just use [network_mode: "host"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode).